# Limiting minimum range of virtual kinect laser scan

Tags: gazebo, navigation, turtlebot, scan, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate a virtual turtlebot creating a map with gmapping in gazebo.

As an answer to a question I asked earlier, I have been advised to limit the minimum distance from the laser a scan must be to be accepted as valid, so that the laser does not pick up the robot itself.

I am having trouble figuring out how to get that done. Does anyone know what the best way to go about that would be? Or where I could read up on making changes like that?

Thanks,
-Ethan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36093/limiting-minimum-range-of-virtual-kinect-laser-scan/) by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
Which driver is producing the original scan data? Some of them provide a minimum range parameter.

**Comment by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on 2012-06-13**:
I don't know how to check which driver that is.

**Comment by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on 2013-09-26**:
I have not worked with gazebo,
but for the actual turtlebot you can check out the parameters of the package "pointcloud_to_laserscan". In this package, a parameter named "~range_min" defines such value for kinect data. (http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, sudhanshu_mittal's solution is fine. I add another option: in

```
turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xacro
```

you have the description of the simulated kinect. Parameters

```
<clip>
    <near>0.05</near>
    <far>8.0</far>
</clip>
```

allows you to set pointcloud depth limits. In fact, I don't know why near limit it's 0.05... should be 0.4!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1